# Why is this series divergent: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \sin\left(\frac n{n^4 + 1}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can anyone explain me why does this serie diverge?!

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 \sin\left(\dfrac n{n^4 + 1}\right)$$

Comment: What does $sen$ stand for?

Comment: Is $\text{sen}$ any special mathematical function or should that not be there?

Comment: sen is sin, I forgot to tell it ( seno spanish, sine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sin(x) is like x when x tends to 0, so this is like the $\sum n^2 * 1 / (n^3)$ which is like $\sum 1/n$

Comment: but what is inside the sine is 1/(n^4) not 1/(n^3)

Comment: @Antonio, what's inside the sine is $n/(n^4+1) \approx n/n^4 = 1/n^3$.